# CUPS on FreeBSD: suitable paths for manual placement of individual PPD files

Tags: freebsd, directory, cups, ppd, trueos

### Background

I downloaded a handful of PPD files for Linux, with an expectation that they will work on TrueOS Desktop, which is currently based on FreeBSD 12.0-CURRENT.

I know that with the web interface to CUPS – typically http://localhost:631/ – there's 'Or Provide a PPD File:' with the option to browse the file system, but I prefer to have the driver listed after I select the relevant make/manufacturer.

### Success, and the question

I experimented with placement of the PPD files at `/usr/local/share/cups/model/other` where the `other` directory was made by me.

Success (example below), but:

- I'd like to know **whether a different path would be more appropriate**.

---

#### Example

```
[gjp4@momh167-gjp4-hpelitebook850g2-trueos /usr/local/share/cups]% ls -l
total 796
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel       9 30 Oct 14:10 banners
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  331836 28 Oct 02:33 calibrate.ppm
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel       5 30 Oct 14:10 charsets
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel      15 30 Oct 14:10 data
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel       4 30 Oct 14:10 drv
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel      13 29 Oct 18:03 examples
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel       9 30 Oct 14:10 mime
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel       5 30 Oct 14:14 model
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel      10 30 Oct 14:10 ppdc
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel       2 14 Oct 20:33 profiles
drwxr-xr-x  7 root  wheel      77 29 Oct 18:03 templates
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  wheel       4 30 Oct 14:10 usb
[gjp4@momh167-gjp4-hpelitebook850g2-trueos /usr/local/share/cups]% cd model
[gjp4@momh167-gjp4-hpelitebook850g2-trueos /usr/local/share/cups/model]% ls -l
total 19
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  20940  5 Oct 22:52 CUPS-PDF.ppd
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     39 24 Oct 23:43 foomatic-db-ppds -> /usr/local/share/foomatic/db/source/PPD
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel      3 30 Oct 14:10 gutenprint
[gjp4@momh167-gjp4-hpelitebook850g2-trueos /usr/local/share/cups/model]% sudo mkdir other
Password:
[gjp4@momh167-gjp4-hpelitebook850g2-trueos /usr/local/share/cups/model]% cd other 
[gjp4@momh167-gjp4-hpelitebook850g2-trueos /usr/local/share/cups/model/other]% sudo cp /usr/home/gjp4/Desktop/BH754ePPDLinux_300000000/English/CUPS1.2/* .
[gjp4@momh167-gjp4-hpelitebook850g2-trueos /usr/local/share/cups/model/other]% sudo cp /usr/home/gjp4/Desktop/BHP1250PPDLinux_320/English/CUPS1.2/* .
[gjp4@momh167-gjp4-hpelitebook850g2-trueos /usr/local/share/cups/model/other]% ls -l
total 284
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   22590 30 Oct 17:39 KO1250opn.ppd
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  497755 30 Oct 17:39 KO1250UX.ppd
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel   24262 30 Oct 17:39 KO754opn.ppd
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  199193 30 Oct 17:39 KO754UX.ppd
[gjp4@momh167-gjp4-hpelitebook850g2-trueos /usr/local/share/cups/model/other]%
```

Selecting a driver that relates to one of the four files that I placed at `/usr/local/share/cups/model/other`:

[image: screenshot of selecting a driver]

Using that driver, a print dialogue:

[image: screenshot of required options within a print dialogue]

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question: the directory you chose is Ok.

**There is no other directory which is more appropriate**.